# How do I delete from the disk pictures I deleted in a folder in Lightroom CC?

Tags: lightroom, file-management

I imported photos into a Lightroom CC folder and deleted a lot of them, but only from the catalogue not from the disk.

Is there a way to delete them from the disk, too, or do I need to sync the folder and start over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who have done the same mistake here is how to proceed:

- In the Library view, right click on a folder and select `Synchronize...`
- Check both `Import new photos` and `Show import dialog before importing` checkboxes and press `Synchronize` button
- On the import view, check `Add to collection` on the right pane and create a new collection and click on the `Import` button
- On the library view, select the newly created collection then select all the photo (press ctrl + a or CMD + a on osx) the mark all as rejected (press x)
- Select back the initial folder, the pictures should be back but all marked as rejected
- The in the Photo top menu, select `Delete rejected photos` then press `Delete from disk`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Lightroom to temporarily move the remaining photos (i.e. that are still referenced by the Lightroom catalogue) to a different location on your disk.
2. Whatever image files are then left on disk in the original folder are the ones you deleted from the Lightroom catalogue.
3. Simply delete those left over image files using your Explorer tool (e.g. Windows Explorer)
4. Use Lightroom to move the catalogued photos back to the original location.

Comment: That is probably working but more complex than the answer of Bambou :)

Comment: Matter of opinion.  I thought it was few steps and simpler personally. :-)